# Getting error LibraryFunction::version from calls to LibraryFunctionLoad

Tags: librarylink

I am having trouble running my program and keep getting this error:

> LibraryFunction::version: The version number 2 of the library is not consistent with the current or any previous WolframLibraryVersion. >>
>   LibraryFunction::initerr: A nonzero error code 7 was returned during the initialization of the library C:\I2C_Control\demo3.dll. >>
>   LibraryFunction::libload: The function I2cScan was not loaded from the file C:\I2C_Control\demo3.dll. >>
>   LibraryFunction::version: The version number 2 of the library is not consistent with the current or any previous WolframLibraryVersion. >>
>   LibraryFunction::initerr: A nonzero error code 7 was returned during the initialization of the library C:\I2C_Control\demo3.dll. >>
>   LibraryFunction::libload: The function I2cWrite was not loaded from the file C:\I2C_Control\demo3.dll. >>
>       ....

How do I change the library version? This is the start of my code:

```
$LibraryPath = ("C:\\I2C_Control")
FindLibrary["demo3"]
I2cScan = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo3", "I2cScan", {}, {Integer, 1}];
I2cWrite = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo3", "I2cWrite", {Integer, {Integer, 1}}, Integer];
I2cRead = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo3", "I2cRead", {Integer, Integer}, {Integer, 1}];
I2cClean = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo3", "I2cClean", {}, Integer];
I2cLine = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo3", "I2cLine", {Integer}, Integer];
...
```

demo3.dll is in the folder I2C_Control. I'm not sure what is going wrong or how to fix this.

Comment: The message indicates a mismatch between the version of the  `WolframLibrary.h` header file used to build the DLL and the kernel loading it.

Comment: Right...how do I fix it?

Comment: Depends on which version created the library and which one is trying to load it, but rebuild the DLL perhaps?